# Why should i use `static` methods in React classes?

Tags: javascript

I feel like i'm missing some crucial benefits of this `static` thing in react.

```
export default class ComponentName extends Component {
  static someMethod = () => {

  }

  static someVariable = {
    a: 'b'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>ComponentName</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Why would i use this instead of regular `const functionName = () => {}` or variables?

Comment: `const functionName = () => {}` will be copied for each instance, static will be defined once.

Comment: additionally, this isn't specific to react. it's specific to javascript classes.

Comment: okay, sounds like explicit advantage of `static`. Then why people don't use it all the time?

Comment: On what stats is your opinion regarding "people are not using it all the time" based?

Comment: no stats, just observations of opensource boilerplates

Comment: statics are quicker and lighter, but since when is quickness a problem for React?

Comment: i didn't say it's a problem. I said, that there must be a reason, why not-static methods are in use.